# Are global variables slower in c due to virtual memory?

Tags: c, operating-system

According to the gfg article on memory layout in c program... Global variables are stored in the data section of a c program, and the data section is a portion of the virtual memory space. So does this mean using global variables is slow since they are in the virtual memory.

Comment: What is "gfg article"? Anyway, in a system that has virtual memory, *all* addresses in a program are virtual.  So the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Everything you use in a C program is in virtual memory space

Answer (score 1):

Every address in a C program (or any other program) is in a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) that is created by the OS.

None of the addresses in the program are real. (In a modern OS)

Why does it use Virtual address space? SECURITY! There is also something called 'ASLR' ([Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)) which goes even further, and makes the addresses random, hence avoids attacks that target known memory locations.

Note: No matter what you change in your program, it will be given a virtual address space. No compiler option will help. (But you **can** disable 'ASLR' by changing some settings in the OS, but it is a security risk to do so).

Comment: Does the virtual address space store the values of the variable ?

Comment: @ashwaths yes. Everything during the run of the program is stored in the virtual address space